# How to create a user in EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS documentation  gives the [procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) to create users.

As `ec2-user`, running below command, gives command syntax error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ whoami
ec2-user
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo useradd -c 'xyz' -m /home/xyz -s /bin/bash -u 1983 xyz
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]

Options:
.....
```

---

This command works fine in my local machine.

On EC2(Amazon machine image), Why `useradd` does not accept this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the versions/environment/etc, seems a little bit like a wild guess, but I asume useradd should be fairly standard across distributions, so at a first glance:

- In our distributions (debian based) you don´t specify "/home/" for the user folder with the parameter -c, as it is added by default
- You are adding some "xyz" at the end, this is the folder name that you already specified with -c, so you can drop it.

The following should work:

```
sudo useradd -c 'xyz' -m xyz -s /bin/bash -u 1983
```